# Unable to click buttons with HtmlUnitDriver but able to click buttons with FirefoxDriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, htmlunit-driver

I have a code using Selinium HtmlUnitDrive. I'm able to access the website and click the ***except cookies*** but I can't seem to click the ***play demo*** button. I don't what is a problem because I can click all buttons using FirefoxDriver.

Before I could not access any elements using HtmlUnitDriver until I used ***WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX, true);***

Can someone assist because I'm looking to use HtmlUnitDriver.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly it's a typo as there are no blank spaces between `Pl` and `ay`. Effectively, you code block would be:

```
//CLICK DEMO BUTTON
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='Play Demo ']"))).click();
System.out.println("DEMO BUTTON CLICKED");
```

Accomodating the *blank space*, you can use:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[normalize-space()='Play Demo']"))).click();
```